# How can I know from page constructor page OnNavigatedTo will be called or not?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to tell from inside a page constructor whether OnNavigatedTo will be called or not? And if I add a page instance to the content of a PivotItem, can I tell if the page constructor is called from pivot control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are embedding pages in a pivot then you won't be able to tell if OnNavigateTo will be called (at least, not from the page constructor).

I would advise against this, it will make things pretty messy. I would suggest you add the page contents to a user control which you can then add to your page or pivot. That way you can add the logic required to the host control (page/pivot).

Comment: But I have many things that I make in page.cs code, particularly in OnNavigatedTo method, and I have 3 pages that I must add in pivot control, so if I do as you say , I must to rewrite man logic in my pivot page. Am I wrong or did you now some solution ?

Comment: The logic in OnNavigatedTo will not be invoked when the page is embedded in a pivot. You need to seperate the UI/logic that is used in both cases into a user control and then add this to your page and your pivot (which I assume is on a seperate page).

Comment: Yes it is in separate page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

User controls which you can embed in a Pivot do not have an onNavigated to overload.

The onNavigated to event will fire for the page that contains the control but nothing else.

If you want to initialise controls within the page separately then you will have to call code from the parent page's onNavigated to or preferably the onLoaded event (remembering you have to enable that manually from either XAML or hooking in to the even in code)

Comment: No I have many logic that I can't do in controls, so I"ll do without controls. So I thought about two solutions. First: to do what I need to do in OnnavigatedTo in constructor and check if constructor is called don't do that in OnNavidatedTo. Second: Rewrite all tree pages codes in Pivot xaml and pivot cs. What solution is better or maybe you know better solution ?